# Culture-specific squabbling

Tags: discussion

This question isn't explicit about which temperature units are being used: [What type of beers stand up to temperature variation during fermentation?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-type-of-beers-stand-up-to-temperature-variation-during-fermentation).

I know how some people love to argue about which cultural-convention is "better", but it could get unpleasant sometimes I suppose.

Do we have/need any policy regarding this sort of thing?

Comment: I'm a lurker of homebrew and I just came to meta to see if this topic was brought up.  I've been finding the measurements units very confusing as a newbie.

Answer (score 7):

*Boy, I'm running into a lot of "we need a policy" and "let's add this to the FAQ" people this morning.*

The "policy" suggestion is to talk to each other like a community — A helpful comment asking for clarification, like any *other* omission in a question: "Did you mean Farenheit or Celcius?"

It's easy enough to change "**21 degrees**" to "**21° C (70° F)**." Editors can do this site wide as a matter of convention.

That's how you improve the quality of a site.

Comment: I would say it's not easy enough.  It's a smell if a bunch of questions have to keep asking the same question for clarification.  IE imagine if there was no way to differentiate between lager and IPA.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a comment stating the conversion (and, in this case, the assumption of degrees C). If the author wants to improve the question by incorporating the comment then so much the better, but if not the conversion is right there for future readers.

Comment: At high enough reputation, there are also wiki functions to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if SE had a unit converter built in. It could take a stab at what units you were using and then convert to whatever a user has set as the default.